# Swift iOS Crop Video in Real Time

Tags: ios, swift, video

There are videos being recorded in a 16:9 ratio and uploaded to s3 and then download to multiple devices (Desktop, Tablets and Phone). Playback of the video that occurs on the on iOS should ratio of 9:16.

My goal is to crop the video playback in real-time to a 9:16, cutting off the outer edges, but also enlarging it if need be. What is the fastest and most efficient way of accomplishing this with Swift?

My concern is CPU overhead doing this on the phone.

Comment: so do you mean to crop before playback after image is stored? or crop for storage after video is taken? or crop each frame as it's taken before it's stored? or make camera video live preview show the desired dimension? each possibility / combination is different

Comment: A crop of the entire video while its playing. When the user hits play, they will only see the cropped video @khjfquantumjj

Comment: So if you are using `AVPlayer` to play the video, can't you use `videoGravity` set to `resizeAspectFill`?